# Is it valid to check boolean value with booleanValue() in this way

Tags: java, android

Is there any reason to check Boolean value in Java (Android preference value)  in this way (found this in legacy code):

```
Boolean isOn = isActivated();
if ( isOn != null && isOn.booleanValue() == false)
```

Comment: No reason for the `== false`, just `!isOn`. `booleanValue()` is redundant after the `null` check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful to distinguish between `boolean` and `Boolean` in Java.

`boolean` is a primitive and cannot be null, but `Boolean` which you are asking about is an object, and can be null (not set). Thus, when dealing with `Boolean`s, it's necessary to check whether the object is null before accessing one of its methods.

Answer (score 0):

This method returns the primitive boolean value of this object.
So if you need the primitive value you can use it like that.